# Is it possible to trigger gitlab-ci pipeline once merge request is accepted on master

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

As part of my project requirement, I have to trigger the pipeline to create a git tag once the merge request is merged to master. But sadly I could not find any option on GitLab-ci. The problem with the below code is the pipeline is getting triggered even if someone is creating merge requests. Any pointers would be really helpful.

```yaml
post-merge:
  only:
    refs:
      - master

  script:
    - echo "Creating a git tag"
    - 'curl -X POST -k -H  "PRIVATE-TOKEN: XXXXXXX" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/1/repository/tags?tag_name=$MODULE-$VERSION&ref=master"'
```

Comment: Just creating a merge request won't trigger a pipeline on the destination branch until the merge request is accepted. Maybe what you saw was a pipeline on the source branch, which was triggered due to the commit, not due to the merge request creation?

Answer (score 0):

You can have stages run only on the master branch, like you did :

```
post-merge:
  only:
    refs:
      - master
```

And they will only run once something was merged into your master branch, considering that you have this branch protected and no one can push without a merge request.